# Text flowing out of second element. In first element it is normal

Tags: html, css

Just look at this: https://glasscity-eisenheim94.c9users.io

[image: Text flowing out]

It has identical styles. I just can't realize how to fix it. I have a deep knowledge in front-end but I can't figure it out.
Things that I have tried:

1. white-space: normal;
2. word-wrap: break-word;
3. word-break: normal;

Comment: Inspecting the text shows that all the spaces are &nbsp's which is the cause of your problem.

Comment: @TimBarnett I found the same problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Examinating your code, you have a bunch of &nbsp's that are destroying your layout. Try replacing them with normal spaces.

Comment: It was WordPress issue with replacing all space with &nbsp's

Comment: I alredy imagine that @Demid. Most of the WYSIWYG editor's always replace code without us noticing. 

The best way to prevent that is using a non-format code editor so it saves as you like it. However, the main problem is that you would not see the preview until you reload the public site.